# Saving data in a UITextField when switching between UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios4

(first UIViewController)I have several UITextfields that will have some number value within them. I use a UIButton to switch to my (second UIViewController). Its when I switch back to my (first viewController) that my information gets reset. How do I save that data?

Comment: Get this book http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Design-Patterns-Erik-Buck/dp/0321535022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:variableTextField forKey@"Key"];

NSString *email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"];
    
emailLogin.text = email;
```

Comment: Using NSUserDefaults is a bad approach in this case. NSUserDefaults should be used to save user data to be used again when relaunching the app. In this case the data only needs to be saved for the lifetime of the app, therefore the data should be stored in the memory. Using a singleton model which holds a strong reference to the string would be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Text fields aren't supposed to contain data, they're supposed to *display* data, from models. As long as the model that provides content to the text field doesn't change, the text field won't.

Just a guess, but you probably need to set the value of the text field in your view controller's `-viewWillLoad`, `-viewDidLoad`, etc. methods. It's difficult to be more specific without seeing code.

Comment: Could you give an example code of setting value of the text field?